Concerning application of variational techniques to nonlinear parabolic PDEs.
I just started my PhD and will work mainly in "Parabolic PDEs".
In my master's, the examples we were taught as applications of nonlinear variational techniques such as-- global critical point theory, techniques of Nehari manifold, techniques of Lagrange multiplier, mountain pass theorem, etc., were all semilinear elliptic PDEs.
I noticed (based on my knowledge) that people mostly use the Fixed-Point theorem (a nonvariational technique) to handle nonlinear parabolic PDEs.
The reason behind this might be as follows-- to apply the variational techniques, one always needs a functional $I: X\to \mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is a Banach space such that the weak formulation of the PDE under consideration can be represented as $$<I'(u), v>_{(X',\, X)} = 0\quad \text{for all $v\in X$},$$ where $X'$ is the dual of $X$. As parabolic PDEs contain first-order time and second-order space derivatives, finding such a functional might be impossible.
So, my question is-- Am I thinking in the right direction? If not, is there any reference to applications of variational techniques to nonlinear parabolic PDEs?

https://wakespace.lib.wfu.edu/bitstream/handle/10339/30397/Tello_wfu_0248M_10040.pdf
